# Testing Laravel route that listens for a webhook

Tags: php, laravel, testing, guzzle

Seems like I am missing something here, but I am struggling to implement a test for Laravel that integrates a SendOwl webhook.

Here is the doc I am using:
https://help.sendowl.com/help/using-web-hooks

Note I have already added the route to `exclude` in `VerifyCSRFToken`

Using `ngrok` (setting the webhook to go to the ngrok url for local dev) I have confirmed that the controller code is working correctly manually, and the webhook works.

What I am stuck on is how to actually implement a test that can automate this. This for example, does not work if you try to assert status, it will be 500.

```
$response = $this->call('post', '/listenhere', ['json'=>json_decode($json, true)]);
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code please

Comment: I am curiously interested in poking around with this. What is the error message that comes with the `500` code.

Answer (score 0):

The `call` method was rolled out with Laravel4.2. It is no longer used to simulate HTTP requests within your tests.

Since v5.2, Laravel provides a `json` helper for testing JSON APIs and their responses.

For example, you can now:

```
$response = $this->post('POST', '/listenhere', json_decode($json, true));
$response->assertStatus(200);
$response->assertJson(['created' => true]);
```