# Testing whether a webhook route is called in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, webhooks

I've developed a [package](https://github.com/mitchdav/sns-laravel) that creates a route to listen for SNS webhooks, and I would like to add some tests to ensure that it works properly.

I am stuck on being able to detect if a specific route (the webhook receiver) is called while running the testsuite.

The Laravel documentation describes how to [test your own routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests) through `$this->get('/')`, but the webhook situation is different as it is being requested by an external service.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47463547/testing-laravel-route-that-listens-for-a-webhook) has been asked that is similar but differs in that the question asks about calling the route through Guzzle.

Comment: To my downvoter, can you please comment as to how I could improve the question?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to work on the assumption that the data WILL be sent by SNS. Your implementation logic ideally starts when and “if” SNS hits your route.